# Difference between "estimate" and "estimates"

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural

There are estimates by analyst in [this page](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/TWTR/analystestimates?CountryCode=US).

In the data table there are "High Estimates", "Low Estimates" and "Mean Estimate".

Somehow with "mean", the word "estimate" is used in singular.
I don't understand why we can't use "High Estimate" or "Mean Estimates".

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

"Mean" is singular because there is only one mean (average) estimate, calculated by using lots of other estimate**s**, such as high ones or low ones.

Imagine estimates are made daily, some will end up being too high and some too low. Those are recorded as such: **high estimates** and **low estimates**. A single average (mean) is then created by using all the estimates; hence the use of singular "mean".

Comment: Maybe it's not a English, but a economical question, why "high estimates" are shown only by a value?

Comment: @ironsand What's confusing is this: **# of Estimates 36.00 23.00 39.00 40.00** The number of estimates must be whole numbers, yet they are displayed using decimal points. Some of those will be high, some will be low, i.e. more than one for both high and low. The first column uses **36 estimates** to produce **one** mean **estimate**.